# Giving database password without hardcoding it in the program

Tags: java, jdbc

**How can we create a  JDBC connection creation logic that does not require the java code to change every time there is change in DB credentials?**

**NOTE:** : The username and password for the DB will be given by the **user**(with special privileges)...full authority is given to him..

What I mean is,
The DB username, password and other details are usually hardcoded inside the java program. What are the other ways we can keep it so that there is no need to change the java code while changing the credentials? 
We have to keep in mind the **privacy and security factor** of the credentials also...

Comment: What kind of java program is it? A standalone appliaction running on thousands of computers all over the wolrd? A corporate app running on a few computers? A client/server app?

Comment: Actually, the database username and password are not usually hard coded inside of a java program. I've written many database connected applications in the past 15 years using Java, and I've never encoded one in the .java file unless it was a throw away toy.

Comment: @StephaneM... Its a client/server app and the buyers want authority over the database and wants an option to be kept for them to change the username and passwords(DB) anytime they want. I am new to all these..thats why confused

Comment: @EdwinBuck...being new to the corporate world I have to come up with some other ways. The applications I did before on my school days were...like you said.. "throw away toys" :(

Comment: If you have a server (other than the database), you could ask the server for the JDBC url.

Comment: @StephaneM ...can u be a bit more clear please ? :(

Comment: Your server can have a service that can be invoked from the client that will return him the (encrypted) jdbc url. It can take any form: REST service, RPC call...

Comment: Why is keeping login credentials in some sort of file (unencrypted) better than hard-coded in program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Store your credentials in a file (credentials.properties)
2. Read the file if your program starts

like this:

```
Properties   properties = new Properties();
properties .load(new FileInputStream(new File("c:\\credentials.properties")));

String user = properties.getProperty("username");
String pass = properties.getProperty("password");
//...
```

The content of credentials.properties looks like this:

```
#DB properties:
driver   = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url      = jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?useEncoding=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
username = dit
password = 123456
```

Comment: @DeepayanNandy so what is the problem?

Comment: I want the user(one with special privileges) to change the credentials...it has to be taken from him... :(

Comment: credentials.properties is a simple text file. Every user can open it and change the properties. Perhaps you should define the real use case more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a properties file for storing all the credentials and database url.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some library that allows you to load configurations from an XML file - I prefer [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). My Database configuration is saved in a configuration XML, the only thing I need to do after changing the credentials is restarting the application.

In order to improve security you might hardcode a decryption key into the application and save the encrypted password into the configuration file.

When my application starts I create a class containing all configurations of the application:

```
public class ConfigurationUtils {
    public static final Config config;

    static {
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.alias("config", Config.class);
        xstream.alias("proxy", Proxy.class);
        xstream.alias("database", Database.class);
        xstream.alias("mailServer", MailServer.class);

        // Check if a configuration file exists, otherwise use the config from the resources
        File file = new File("/etc/applicationname/config.xml");

        if(file.exists()) {
            config = (Config) xstream.fromXML(file);
        } else {
            ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("config.xml");
            config = (Config) xstream.fromXML(is);
        }
    }
}
```

The referenced classes are simple data classes consisting of private attributes, getters and setters that match the names in the config.xml - XStream handles the mapping of the XML values to the class.

Comment: So who is actually changing the credentials? I want the user(one with special privileges) to change the credentials...it has to be taken from him....

Comment: The person who has the client installed is able to edit the XML file containing the configuration parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is an interactive program, you pop up a dialog box which can take the username and password from the user. If it is a command line program, you can specify username and password on the command line and access these values in the 'args' variable in the 'public static void main(String[] args) method. If it is a batch program which has no user interaction, you can use any of the methods mentioned by other contributors above.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do. And to be clear, I only play with toys.

- Database < Service
- Service

  - decrypts traffic from the client
  - has a "config" or "properties" file with the user name and password to interact with the database.
  - can respond in a way you prefer based on your security needs

Somewhere else:

- Client > Service

  - A user can log in.
  - the logged in user can then send requests or submit data to the service
  - the service would decide how to respond, creating a log in the database of the query you made and from where and if it meets the specifications of your least access control model, the service will execute your needs.

The service would also be in charge of scrubbing the badness from getting in.

You can then tie this interaction to a single sign on feature that's tied to window's or linux's user and group controls with something like a UUID or even slide it into a web app in the forms of a cookie.

You no longer have the "username" and "password" anywhere visible to anyone who wouldn't normally have access to it.

I think this might be how companies do it, but I wouldn't know because I rarely know what I'm talking about and therefore am not hirable.